# Can i pass instance of interface to attributes in .net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, attributes, asp.net-core-webapi

```
public class HMACAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
   public HMACAuthenticationAttribute(IUser user)  
   {
     .....
   }
}
```

The above is my class attribute. I want to call this in below controller.Is there any way to call the above class.

```
[HMACAuthentication()]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102138/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-an-attribute

Comment: I'm able to pass the strings as param but i'm unable to pass the instance of interface as param.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404594/how-to-call-attribute-which-is-having-parameterinterface-in-constructor-from-c    follow this link.We will get the answer easly.