# How to call attribute which is having parameter(interface) in constructor from controller

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, attributes, asp.net-core-webapi

```
public class HMACAuthenticationAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
    {
       public HMACAuthenticationAttribute(IUser user)  
       {
         .....
       }
    }
```

Above code is attribute class and below code is controller. I want to call attribute with parameter

```
[HMACAuthentication()]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense for an attribute to accept interfaces, given that the arguments have to be compile-time constants.

One way is that you could register your interfaces as services and get them using below code without constructor injection.For example:

1.Interface:

```
public interface IUserService
{
   //..
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
  //..
}
```

2.In startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();
}
```

3.Custom Authorization Attribute

```
public class HMACAuthenticationAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{

    public HMACAuthenticationAttribute()
    {

    }
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();

    }
}
```

Update:

Another way is that you could also use `[ServiceFilter]` or `[TypeFilter]` by DI,refer to

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#servicefilterattribute

1.In startup, register `HMACAuthenticationAttribute`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddScoped<HMACAuthenticationAttribute>();
   services.AddSingleton<IUserService, UserService>();
}
```

2.Custom Authorization Attribute

```
public class HMACAuthenticationAttribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{

    public HMACAuthenticationAttribute(IUserService user)
    {

    }

}
```

3.Controller

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(HMACAuthenticationAttribute))]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much you saved lot of time for me.

Comment: The key point is GetRequiredService.thanks.