# Replace custom placeholder in attribute routing in .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I replace custom placeholder before each route in `.Net Core 2.1`

For Example `{serverkey}`

```
[Route("api/{serverkey}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [AuthorizationFilter]
    public class MonitoringController : Controller
    {
        // Code...
    }
```

I want each url to be like `api/key/Monitoring/Action`. So I need to replace key in each request/route.

So basically is there any way to replace the placeholder `{serverkey}` or something like this `{serverkey:key}` or even `[serverkey]` before each request map to this controller.

I know there could be a way like `[controller]` is replaced automatically by `.net core` but I am not able to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `{serverKey}` value coming from?

Comment: What do you mean by replaced? Putting a `[Route("api/{serverkey}/[controller]")]` attribute on top of your controller, and accessing the value in your action methods (like this `[HttpGet] public string Get(string serverkey)`) isn't enough?

Comment: I have added `serverKey` in appsetting.json. But i need to find a way to replace route placeholder with this key.

Comment: @Voodoo What happens is the `serverkey` provided in the url doesn't match the one in the appsettings file? I think you could deal with that with a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`

Comment: @bmartins I don't want to get the key from input, but I want my route to be replaced by my own key stored.

Comment: @bmartins See I don't want to pass key at all, but I want my route to be modified according to the key so that it can pass the custom rules written in nginx on server.

Comment: @Voodoo What do you mean by "I don't want to pass the key"? Consider that the `serverKey` is `xxx` in the `appsettings.json`. What happens if a user calls the endpoint `api/xxx/monitoring/action`? What happens for the endpoint `api/yyy/monitoring/action`?

Comment: @bmartins It will simply return 404

Comment: Are you thnking of route constraints? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-route-constraints

Comment: @MarkDavies No. Constraint will check whether the key is valid or not. Am i right? But i want my url to be replaced by actual key, so that the swagger will generate urls by prepending the key. Is this making sense?

Comment: @Voodoo If only one `serverKey` value is possible, why do you want to pass it in the url? Is it a clumsy workaround to avoid setting up an authentication mechanism?

Comment: I can't. Actually we have API service which we are injecting it into the other services to reuse. So we want to prep-end the key to pass the custom server rules written in nginx. So the key will change based on the service which are using our common service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to create custom `route` using [IRouteTemplateProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.iroutetemplateprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
public class CustomRouteAttribute : Attribute, IRouteTemplateProvider
    {
        string serverKey = string.Empty;

        public CustomRouteAttribute()
        {
            string serverKey = "Your Key";
        }

        public string Template => $"api/{serverKey}/[controller]";

        public int? Order { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

It will prepend your key before each `route`.

**Usage**: Use this as a `attribute` on your `controller`

```
//[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [CustomRoute]
    [ApiController]
    public class DemoController : ControllerBase
    {}
```

For **Example**:

`http://localhost:52264/api/Controller/Action` will becomes 
`http://localhost:52264/api/Yourkey/Controller/Action`

Comment: I am also interested to implement something similar. How would your full code sample look like, if the serverKey would be read from a json settings file? How could this be injected into the CustomRouteAttribute class?

Comment: You can check these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102138/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-an-attribute and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915192/dependency-injection-in-attributes