# Dependency injection in custom attribute in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, attributes

I have very simple question that how can I resolve `dependency` in `custom attributes`

```
public class CustomRouteAttribute : Attribute, IRouteTemplateProvider
    {
        string serverKey = string.Empty;

        // Parameterised constructor
        // Need to resolve it automatically without passing it explicitly
        public CustomRouteAttribute(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            serverKey = configuration.GetSection("serverkey").Value;
        }

        public string Template => $"api/{serverKey}/[controller]";

        public int? Order { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I know without `parameterised constructor` I can use it without any problem like this:

```
    [CustomRoute]
    [ApiController]
    public class DemoController : ControllerBase
    {
        // Code....
    }
```

So my question is: How can I use `dependency injection` in `custom attributes`.

I know there could be a way like we do in `custom filters`. We can use dependency injection in our `custom filter` and use it with [TypeFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.typefilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) or [ServiceFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.servicefilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

**Example** `[TypeFilter(typeof(ExampleActionFilter))]`

Comment: TypeFilter/ServiceFilter implement [IFilterFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.ifilterfactory?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102138/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-an-attribute

Comment: The question which is tagged as similar is not for `.Net Core` and I am not using any third party container to resolve dependencies like `Unity`