# How can i use dependency injection in my custom attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, custom-attributes

How can i use dependency injection in my custom attribute?
Hi,i am writing an custom attribute and i need use some interface method on my custom attribute . so  need to build contractor for inject my service(interface), if i do this
when I want to use my attribute, it requires an input of that interface type, what can i do?

[image]

To be honest, I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: You should prevent doing dependency injection into attributes completely. Credits of all info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916075/14322498

Comment: Strictly speaking, we cannot use dependency injection to inject a dependency into an attribute. You can refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102138/how-to-use-dependency-injection-with-an-attribute) to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

You can use TypeFilter coupled with an attribute using normal DI with nothing special see example(async) below

Controller method decorated with attribute:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(TestAttribute))]
public async Task CreateAsync()
{
    //your method here
    return null;
}
```

Attribute:

```
public class TestAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

    public TestAttribute(IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _identityService = identityService;

    }
    public async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = await _identityService.CurrentUser();

        if (user.TestId == null)
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```